# CakePHP model associations via an intermediary table?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, models, table-relationships

I have a Home model that links to a Realtor model on Home.realtor_num = Realtor.num.
I have an Office model linked to the Realtor model on Realtor.office_num = Office.num.

Suppose I want easy access to Office.name in the result set of a find on the Homes table.  Is there an easy way to specify the above relationship, such that $home['Office']['name'] will contain the data I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have correctly setup associations in you models:

1. you can use containable behavior,
2. you can access Office model from HomeController: `$this->Home->Realtor->Office->find(...)`

Comment: Thanks, sounds simple when put that way.  I'll give it a try!